# Why are not all images showing up in this slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var startSlider = function() {
                var startSlide = $(".slider li:first");
                var nextSlide = $(".active").next("li");
                $(".active").removeClass();

                if(nextSlide.html() == null) {
                    nextSlide = startSlide;
                }

                nextSlide.addClass("active");

                setTimeout(startSlider, 1000);
            };

            setTimeout(startSlider, 1000);
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        .active{
            display:none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="slider" style="list-style:none;">
    <li><div class="active" style="background:#F00;height:100px;width:100px;margin:6px; position: fixed; top: 100px;"></div></li>
    <li><div style="background:#0F0;height:100px;width:100px;margin:6px; position: fixed; top:100px;"></div></li>
    <li><div style="background:#00F;height:100px;width:100px;margin:6px; position: fixed; top:100px;"></li>
    <li><div style="background:#000;height:100px;width:100px;margin:6px; position: fixed; top: 100px;"></div></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run this code only blue and black divs show up again and again.What can be the posible reason for that? I tried to put active class at different position but it did not help.I removed the typo suggested in answer it was not in the original code and showed up only here.

Comment: If you edit your question, please specify what update you've done in the question, instead of directly editing and saving it.

Comment: Where are the images? There's only a div inside all of the four `li` tags.

Comment: I am just using div for now. Putting images is not supposed to have any effect I think. It is just about toggling classes I think.

Comment: The `div` inside the third `li` doesn't have a closing tag.

Comment: It is still not working after adding a closing div tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script will set `class="active"` to one of the four divs at a time starting with the first div.
Since this is the definition of `active` CSS class

```
<style>
    .active{
        display:none;
    }
</style>
```

The current div that have `class="active"` will disappear but the other three won't, and they're placed in the exact same position so only the darker colors can be seen, which are blue and black in this case.

I would suggest using two CSS classes as follows

```
<style>
    .active{
        display:block;
    }
    .inactive{
        display:none;
    }
</style>
```

and changing your script to make one div have `class="active"` and the rest have `class="inactive"` at a time, meaning the `active` div will appear and the `inactive` divs will disappear.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var startSlider = function() {
            var startSlide = $(".slider li:first");
            var nextSlide = $(".active").next("li");

            // remove css class from all divs
            $(".active").removeClass();
            $(".inactive").removeClass();

            if(nextSlide.html() == null) 
            {nextSlide = startSlide;}

            // set nextSlide css class to active
            nextSlide.addClass("active");

            // set the rest of the divs css class to inactive
            nextSlide.siblings().addClass("inactive");

            setTimeout(startSlider, 1000);
        };
        setTimeout(startSlider, 1000);
    });

</script>
```

Here's the complete code after making the changes above.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var startSlider = function() {
            var startSlide = $(".slider li:first");
            var nextSlide = $(".active").next("li");

            // remove css class from all divs
            $(".active").removeClass();
            $(".inactive").removeClass();

            if(nextSlide.html() == null) 
            {nextSlide = startSlide;}

            // set nextSlide css class to active
            nextSlide.addClass("active");

            // set the rest of the divs css class to inactive
            nextSlide.siblings().addClass("inactive");

            setTimeout(startSlider, 1000);
        };
        setTimeout(startSlider, 1000);
    });

</script>
<style>
    .active{
        display:block;
    }
    .inactive{
        display:none;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <ul class="slider" style="list-style:none;">
    <li><div class="active" style="background:#F00;height:100px;width:100px;margin:6px; position: fixed; top: 100px;"></div></li>
    <li><div class="inactive" style="background:#0F0;height:100px;width:100px;margin:6px; position: fixed; top:100px;"></div></li>
    <li><div class="inactive" style="background:#00F;height:100px;width:100px;margin:6px; position: fixed; top:100px;"></div></li>
    <li><div class="inactive" style="background:#000;height:100px;width:100px;margin:6px; position: fixed; top: 100px;"></div></li>
    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's the working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k8qod5g0/

Comment: Please check the updated answer, I think it's what you're looking for.