# Perform some executions every few seconds in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Here is the code that I want to replace

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var startSlider = function() {
        var startSlide = $(".slider li:first");
        var nextSlide = $(".active").next("li");
        $(".active").removeClass();
        $(".inactive").removeClass();
        if(nextSlide.html() == null) 
        {nextSlide = startSlide;}
        nextSlide.addClass("active");
        nextSlide.siblings().addClass("inactive");
        setTimeout(startSlider, 4000);
    };
    setTimeout(startSlider, 100);
});
```

I want to remove startSlider function and use

```
setTimeout( function(){ 
var startSlide = $(".slider li:first");
        var nextSlide = $(".active").next("li");
        $(".active").removeClass();
        $(".inactive").removeClass();
        if(nextSlide.html() == null) 
        {nextSlide = startSlide;}
        nextSlide.addClass("active");
        nextSlide.siblings().addClass("inactive");
  }
 , 4000 );
```

But it does not work any suggestions?

Comment: Define "does not work" - do you get an error? It does something unexpected?

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: The slides don't fade away as they were when I use startSlider.

Comment: Can you please provide a fiddle so that we can understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your first code it works as it is recursive function. But with your second code, you need to use setInterval instead of setTimeout function, which would run every 4 seconds:

```
setInterval( function(){ // consider using setInterval instead of setTimeout
var startSlide = $(".slider li:first");
        var nextSlide = $(".active").next("li");
        $(".active").removeClass();
        $(".inactive").removeClass();
        if(nextSlide.html() == null) 
        {nextSlide = startSlide;}
        nextSlide.addClass("active");
        nextSlide.siblings().addClass("inactive");
  }
 , 4000 );
```

Comment: It is working now. But when the page loads for first time the slide takes a little longer to change.

Comment: @RajatPaul if this is related to your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26075248/1905949, I guess you need to change `$(".slider li:first")` to `$(".slider li:nth-child(2)")`

Comment: How does that help me?

Comment: @RajatPaul it's because when the page is loaded for the first time, it waits 4 seconds before the function is executed. When the function is executed for the first time, the first div will be set to `active`, so the first div will be active for 8 seconds. Does that make sense?